# How do I figure out how Postgres was installed on my Linux system?

Tags: postgresql, linux, startup

I'm using Postges 9.6 on Ubuntu Linux 16.  I'm trying to figure out how the Postgres server was installed so I can figure out a command to start and stop it.  It evidently isn't installed as a Linux service

```
[rails@server ~]$ sudo service postgresql status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status postgresql.service
Unit postgresql.service could not be found.
```

"which psql" reveals

```
[rails@server ~]$ which psql
/usr/bin/psql
```

I'm sort of at a loss for the next steps in figure out the command to start and stop it.

Comment: What does `dpkg -l | grep postgres` say?

Comment: It returns nothing

Comment: What about `locate postgres`? It might produce a lot of output.

Comment: Sure did.  I coudl include all of it as an edit to my question but probably the most relevant thing it spat back was "/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgres".

Comment: How about `dpkg -S "/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgres"`?

Comment: It reports "dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgres" despite the fact that "ls /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgres" does return a directory.

Comment: Maybe someone compiled it by hand. Are the normal build tools (gcc, make) installed?

Comment: Yes, the build tools are there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply looking to start and stop it, and a `service` or `systemctl` module doesn't exist on your machine, you can use `pg_ctl` to start and stop the Postgres server.  You will also need to have the path to the data directory handy (typically, the folder that contains `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf`), and pass that in along with the `-D` flag:

`pg_ctl -D /path/to/data_dir start|stop`

If no data directory exists, you will either need further assistance to help you get an existing database cluster up and running, or you can use `initdb` to create a new database cluster